# rails server ошибка

Tags: ruby-on-rails

спасибо за ответы, проделал действия которые были предложены, теперь ситуация выглядит так:

```
C:\Sites\railsProjects\firstApp>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (r
equired)>': undefined method `configure' for #<FirstApp::Application:0x297ab78>
(NoMethodError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-
4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (r
equired)>'
        from C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/railsProjects/firstApp/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib
/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.0.2
/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

браузер всё ещё не открывает страницу

вылаживаю свой development.rb

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false
  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true
  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26638287/6104996 не оно?  или может это поможет: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17762417/6104996

Comment: проверяйте установку необходимых `gems`

Comment: Выложите свой `config/environments/development.rb`

Comment: @MAXOPKA добавил

Comment: есть ли у вас юниксовые утилиты? вообщем погрепайте: `grep FirstApp -r` в папке приложения

Comment: @MaDDi Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Метод "Rails.application.configure" принимает на вход блок с одним параметром. Нужно этот параметр указать:

```
Rails.application.configure do |config|
  # ...
end
```

Таким образом переменная "config" будет определена в блоке.